# Java RESTFULL usando Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

Galera, estou tentando desenvolver um projeto em Java com um Web Service REST, sou novo nesse negócio de Web Service, então estou meio perdido. Eu não consigo acessar o meu serviço pela URL do navegador, quando eu coloco o endereço do Serviço, o navegador responde com o erro "404". Por favor, me ajudem, já importei as libs do Jersey e etc ... Após várias pesquisas, não encontrei onde estou errando. Abaixo segue o meu código do web.xml e da classe de Serviço. Desde já agradeço!

O meu web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="2.5">

  <!-- COMO DEFAULT, O NOME DO MEU PROJETO, ESSE NOME IRÁ APARECER NA URL -->
  <display-name>Cast_Frotas</display-name> 

  <!-- MAPEANDO O SERVLET-->
  <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTfull</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>br.com.Cast_frotas.service</param-value>
    </init-param> 

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTfull</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

A minha classe de serviço

```
package br.com.Cast_frotas.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import br.com.Cast_frotas.controle.CtrlCurso;
import br.com.Cast_frotas.model.Curso;

@Path("/curso")
public class CursoService {

    @GET
    @Path("/teste")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String teste(){
        String txt = "<html>" + "<title>" + "TESTE Serviço" + "</title>"
                + "<body>" + "<h1>" + "Acessei o serviço" + "</h1>"
                + "</body>" + "</html>";
        return txt;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/insert")
    public void inserirCurso(Curso c){
        new CtrlCurso().insert(c);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/select")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Curso> getListAll(){
        List<Curso> lista_cursos = new ArrayList<Curso>();

        lista_cursos = new CtrlCurso().getList();

        return lista_cursos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está misturando configurações das versões do Jersey 1.x e 2.x no seu `web.xml`. A seguinte propriedade pertence a versão 1.x:

```
com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
```

A propriedade correspondente na versão 2.x é:

```
jersey.config.server.provider.packages
```

Dessa forma, seu `web.xml` ficaria assim:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="2.5">

  <!-- COMO DEFAULT, O NOME DO MEU PROJETO, ESSE NOME IRÁ APARECER NA URL -->
  <display-name>Cast_Frotas</display-name> 

  <!-- MAPEANDO O SERVLET-->
  <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTfull</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>br.com.Cast_frotas.service</param-value>
    </init-param> 

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTfull</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Caso o erro 404 continue ocorrendo e esteja utilizando o *server* Tomcat, clique com o botão direito nele, clique em *clear* e reinicie o servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Felipe! Eu fiz isso, mas continua dando o erro 404, será que estou digitando a url errada? Eu inicializo o Servidor Tomcat, vou no navegador e digito: localhost:8080/ + nome do meu projeto/ + rest / + curso/ + teste/...     Seria assim?

Comment: @Matheus Minguini Tente remover a barra ao final assim localhost:8080/ + nome do meu projeto/ + rest / + curso/ + teste

Comment: Felipe, deu certo! Muito obrigado! Muito sucesso pra você!